# React native context api not updated

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using RN NetInfo to check if user connected to internet using component `<NetworkProvider />` and I want to pass this components `stats` to all screens and components in my app.

The problem is context api works good when I use it inside `render` function but when I use inside `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount` the state not changed. Return initial value of `isConnected` state.
**Please read comment in code**

so this my code

NetworkProvider.js

```
import React,{PureComponent} from 'react';
import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';

export const NetworkContext = React.createContext({ isConnected: true });

export class NetworkProvider extends React.PureComponent {

  state = {
    isConnected: true // initial value
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectivityChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectivityChange);
  }

  handleConnectivityChange = isConnected => this.setState({ isConnected });

  render() {
    return (
      <NetworkContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </NetworkContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

this index.js

```
...
import { NetworkContext } from '../components/NetworkProvider';

export default class index extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = {};
    static contextType = NetworkContext;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        ...
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // return object state but with inital value {isConnected :true}
        console.log(this.context);
        //this.fetchData(this.state.page);      
    }

    render() {
        // here when I use this.context return object {isConnected:true/false} depends on internet connection status on device

        return(
                <FlatList
                ...
                />
        )
    }
}
...
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are trying to do because you are only Providing context. You are not consuming it anywhere.

Comment: @azium I've updated my code (index.js)